# Wireless Connection Drops, Mac OS X 10.6.4

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, wireless-networking

I am not sure if this correlates with installing the 10.6.4 update, but I have made no hardware changes to my machine. The wireless connections just drops occasionally, and the only way to pick it back up is to shut off airport and then put it back on.

1. What might be causing this?
2. Are there any fixes?
3. What is the easiest way to "bounce" the connection from the command-line or an icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check out [this](http://appletoolbox.com/2010/06/mac-os-x-10-6-4-wi-fiairport-problems-fixes/) thread.  It looks like a possible fix might be [resetting the SMC (System Management Controller)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US).

Comment: Thanks @jrc03c... I followed the instructions to a "t" (tea?), but since the problem is intermittent I won't know for a bit. +1 in any case.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure what's happening, it might have been due to switching from WEP to WPA-PSK -> computer kept dropping off (even though other computers stayed). But anyway, I'll mark this as best answer, thanks again.